# How to resolve these errors "[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1" in tfs

Tags: git, tfs

How to resolve these errors in tfs

"error: pathspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git",

"[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1"

Comment: i am actually trying to run shell script in tfs2017 that's gonna trigger a job in our application, but tfs is throwing above errors

Comment: You can edit your question. Which command did you ran exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This could be similar to [`Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks` issue 2740](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/2740#issuecomment-310656491), should you see something like:

```
##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin 
##[command]git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/master 
  error: pathspec 'refs/remotes/origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git. 
##[error]Git checkout failed with exit code: 1
```

> I could be wrong, but I think it's because your Git repository is empty and might not yet have a `master` branch.
> You can try queuing the job manually in Jenkins and you'll probably see the same error there.

Make sure your repo as at least one commit on the `master` branch.